# Does Jenkins (not Jenkins X) have gitops support?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup Kubernetes for my company.  I have looked a good amount into Jenkins X and, while I really like the roadmap, I have come the realization that it is likely not mature enough for my company to use at this time.  ([UI in preview](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-jenkins-x-distribution/latest/user-interface/), [flaky command line](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/6352), [random IP address needs](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/6398) and poor windows support are a few of the issues that have lead me to that conclusion.)

But I understand that the normal Jenkins is very mature and can run on Kubernetes.  I also understand that it can have dynamically created build agents run in the cluster.

But I am not sure about gitops support.  When I try to google it (`gitops jenkins`) I get a bunch of information that includes Jenkins X.

**Is there an easy(ish) way for normal Jenkins to use GitOps?  If so, how?**

**Update:**
By GitOps, I mean something similar to what Jenkins X supports.  (Meaning changes to the cluster stored in a Git repository.  And merging causes a deployment.)

Comment: GitOps is a buzzword with different meaning for different people. Jenkins is designed for being triggered from Git changes and checkout code. Some narrow meaning of GitOps is only supported by Flux.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean something similar to what Jenkins X supports. (Meaning changes to the cluster stored in a Git repository. And merging causes a deployment.)

Yes, this is the what Jenkins (or other CICD tools) do. You can declare a deployment pipeline in a [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) that is triggered on merge (commit to master) and have other steps for other branches (if you want).

I recommend to deploy with [kubectl using kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) and store the config files in your Git repository. You *parameterize* different environments e.g. staging and production with [overlays](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#bases-and-overlays). You may e.g. deploy with only 2 replicas in staging but with 6 replicas and more memory resources in production.

Using Jenkins for this, I would create a [docker agent image](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) with `kubectl`, so your *steps* can use the `kubectl` command line tool.

**Jenkins on Kubernetes**

> But I understand that the normal Jenkins is very mature and can run on Kubernetes. I also understand that it can have dynamically created build agents run in the cluster.

I have not had the best experience with this. It may work - or it may not work so well. I currently host Jenkins outside the Kubernetes cluster. I think that [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/blog/2019/02/19/jenkins-x-next-gen-pipeline-engine/) together with [Tekton](https://tekton.dev/) may be an upcoming promising solution for this, but I have not tried that setup.